# angular: total of all country in each row when select option "ALL"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have table in which i have 2 diff. values of each countries(month-wise), when i select each country on select box it works fine but when i select "ALL" option i need total of all the values contain in all countries(month wise).i.e. 
**{{month.A}} should 46(JAN), 56(FEB) and {{month.S}} should 38(JAN) and 28(FEB).**

Also please guide me for ALL option doesn't appear well in select box.
 fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/tffv2owp/

```
$scope.months =
    [{ "country": "UK", "mon": "JAN", "A": "14", "S": "2"},
     { "country": "AUSTRIA", "mon": "JAN", "A": "24", "S": "12"},
     { "country": "ITALY", "mon": "JAN",  "A": "5", "S": "21"},
     { "country": "SWIZ", "mon": "JAN",  "A": "3", "S": "3"},
     { "country": "UK", "mon": "FEB", "A": "4", "S": "12"},
     { "country": "AUSTRIA", "mon": "FEB", "A": "24", "S": "12"},
     { "country": "ITALY", "mon": "FEB",  "A": "15", "S": "1"},
     { "country": "SWIZ", "mon": "FEB",  "A": "13", "S": "3"}
    ];
```

Comment: there is no "all" option in the dropdown - do you mean initial?

Comment: yes, i need it for initial "ALL" option with total of options in both the months.

Comment: `<td >{{month.A}}</td>` for example is printed correctly

Comment: I want "ALL" option to be visible all time.

Comment: And  selecting ,"ALL" option I want only 2 columns . right now there are 5 colms at page loads.

Comment: hm i posted the answer before that last comment...where is the difficulty to do it in 2 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain an aggregate of the values in the filter function. If "ALL" is provided, then recaluclate aggregates (or if these are likely to stay the same calculate once and cache). [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tffv2owp/4/) is an example of recalculating each time the filter is applied. And the important additions:

```
// Add an "ALL" value to countries
$scope.countries = ["ALL", "UK", "AUSTRIA", "ITALY", "SWIZ"];

// ...

app.filter('filterMultiple',['$filter',function ($filter) {
    // maintain singleton aggregate to prevent max $digest cycle
    // each month would go here -- start each value (e.g. A, S) at 0
    var aggregateItems = [
        {mon: 'JAN', A: 0, S: 0},
        {mon: 'FEB', A: 0, S: 0}
    ];
    return function (items, keyObj) {
        var filterObj = {
            /* filterObj remains same */
        };

        // check for 'ALL' Selection
        if (keyObj && keyObj.country === 'ALL') {
            var aggs = {};
            // 0 out aggregate values to recalculate
            angular.forEach(aggregateItems, function (obj) {
                obj.A = 0;
                obj.S = 0;

                // reverse lookup by month
                aggs[obj.mon] = obj;
            });

            // aggregate months / items
            angular.forEach(items, function (obj) {
                aggs[obj.mon].A = aggs[obj.mon].A + (parseInt(obj.A, 10) || 0);
                aggs[obj.mon].S = aggs[obj.mon].S + (parseInt(obj.S, 10) || 0);
            });

            // totals calculated
            return aggregateItems;
    } else if(keyObj){
        // Your original logic
    }

    return filterObj.filteredData;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just insert the "all" option manually:

```
<option value="">All</option>
```

updated your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tffv2owp/1/

Comment: Hi, but I also want  only 2 columns. When all option is selected. Rt now all data is repeated instead I want function which make calc. And show the result. . so only 4 values  generated by sum function.

Comment: Click on another option you will see 2 columns only. Same I want for all option.

Comment: how should this be possible with that table structure? there are several months, so how should the table look like??

Comment: Table will look same as other countries get selected. Only thing is value of "A," will be sum of all countries value "A".

Comment: hey, i've had no time anymore because i have to leave now. updated that fiddle - initial its working, but not if you select the "ALL" after selecting another option - https://jsfiddle.net/tffv2owp/2/